# how to check and add properties to array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to add two keys inside the array object in javascript.

In object `obj` in place of title, add `label and value` in javascript.

Each children key may have children key, if it has children and title key, add label and value key in javascript

```
var obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Category"
    children: [
    {
    id:1, 
    title: "countries", 
    children: [
        {title: "IN", id:1},
        {title: "TH", id:2},
        {title: "SG", id:3}
      ]
    }, {
    id:2, 
    title: "fields", 
    children: [
        {title: "Finance", id:1},
        {title: "Services", id:2}
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
]

function changeObj(obj){
    if (obj.length > 0) {
    var result = obj.map(e => {
      if('children' in e)
        e.children = e.children.map(child => {
          if ('children' in child) 
            child.children = child.children.map(c =>({
             label: c.title,
             value: c.title
              })
            );
            return child;
        });      
      return e
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

```
Expected Output
 {
    label: "Category",
    value: "Category",
    children: [
    {
    label: "countries", 
    value: "countries",
    children: [
        {label:"IN",value:"IN", title: "IN"},
        {label:"TH",value:"TH", title: "TH"},
        {label:"SG",value:"SG", title: "SG"}
      ]
    },{
    label: "fields", 
    value: "fields",
    children: [
        {label: "Finance", value: "Finance",title: "Finance"},
        {label: "Services", value: "Services",title: "Services"}
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: So, what's the actual output? What issue are you having?

Comment: @Lennholm thanks for reply, I have added the expected output in the code,I want to add label and value key if it has children key,title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it.

```js
function changeObj(obj) {
    if(!obj.length) return;

    obj.forEach(i => {
        const title = i.title;
        const child = i.children;

        if(i.id) {
            delete i.id;
        }
        if(i.title) {
            delete i.title;
        }
        
        i.label = title;
        i.value = title;

        if(child) {
            changeObj(child);
        } else {
            i.title = title;
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: While this is perfectly correct, map would better express intent. You should also be mindful of providing a full answer to what would appear to be homework as it misses a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JS syntax it could be implemented this way

```
let __f = (_) => {
    let {title, children} = _;
    const value = title;
    const label = title;
    let result;
    if (children && children.length) {
        result = {label, value, children: children.map(__f)};
    } else {
        result = {label, value, title};
    }
    return result;
};

let result = obj.map(__f).pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

in this instance `obj` is an array of objects as denoted by `[...]`. Arrays can be iterated over using built in functions. In your case, you wish to take each item in the array and alter it in some fashion. You will have the same number of elemnents at the end as you had at the beginning.

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function passes each element in the source array to a function, populating a new array with the results of that function. The docs provide examples.

You should solve for adding the label and value to the top-level object, then delete the title from the top-level object. When you have that working, apply the same approach to the children.

```
[{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }].map(item => ({ ...item, b: item.a + 1 }));
// [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 3 }]
```

Get used to reading the docs, they will be your first source when solving a problem.